# Passing ID's of "to be" Deleted Rows to an INSTEAD OF trigger - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am trying to delete a record from my DB where there are multiple foreign key restraints.
My data/tables look something like this:

```
    CustomerDocuments
    --------------------------
    Blah|Blah|Blah|FK_StreamId

    AttachedDocuments
    --------------------------
    FK_StreamId|Blah|Blah|

    CheckedDocuments
    --------------------------
    FK_StreamId| Blah|Blah

    MembershipDocuments
    --------------------------
    FK_StreamId| Blah| Blah
```

I want to create a INSTEAD OF trigger, where I check the other document tables for the matching stream id, and delete the record from these tables before deleting the record in the Customer Documents Table.

My trigger would be something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgCustomerDocument_D] 
   ON   [dbo].[CustomerDocument]
   INSTEAD OF DELETE 
AS 
BEGIN
//check AttachDocuments table  for steam id, if exists, then delete
//check MembershipDocuments table  for steam id , if exists, then delete
//check CheckedDocuments table for steam id, if exists, then delete
//finally delete record from main table
```

However, I'm not sure how to pass the stream_id to the trigger?
Is this the right approach? I'm not overly familiar with SQL.

I suppose to I could created a stored proc to do so, but this would take alot of reworking of existing code to incorporate this. So I was really hopeful to be able to achieve this with just a trigger.

Comment: I would suggest using cascading foreign key references.  Why write a trigger if you don't have to?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've never heard of cascading foreign key references.  I'll look into this.